# Swift Concurrency: Hold off Tasks until certain data is loaded

Tags: swift, concurrency, swift-concurrency

I've been using Swift Concurrency for 2 years, but can't get my head around how to resolve this situation.

In a class named `APIManager`, there is an execute method that performs a network call.
When the server responds with a 401, the bearer token needs to be refreshed & the call retried.

Looks roughly like this:

```swift
class APIManager {
   func execute<R: ResponseProtocol>(request: RequestProtocol, response: R) async throws -> R.Value {
       let session = getURLSession()
       let urlRequest: URLRequest = request.buildURLRequest()

       let (data, urlResponse) = try await session.data(for: urlRequest)

       if let httpURLResponse = urlResponse as? HTTPURLResponse,
          httpURLResponse.statusCode == 401 {
          try await renewBearerToken()
          return try await execute(request: request, response: response)
       }

       return decode(data: data)
   }
}
```

There is only one instance of this class (injected into every service).
Tasks are fired randomly around the application (like on button clicks), and invoke this method.

What I would like to achieve is whenever the class is loading data, especially when refreshing a token, make sure any other parallel fired Task waits for its completion before also completing the call (or it might risk hitting that 401 too).

Any ideas if and how this can be enforced? TaskGroups, Actors?

Comment: I think the right answer using Swift concurrency is to use an actor. In olden days I would have said use a serial dispatch queue, but actors provide equivalent functionality.

Comment: @JeremyP Thanks! Didn't know Actors matched a serial dispatch queue, thought were just about thread-safe access. Sweet :)

Comment: @Rob Thank you, but no worries, we re-use an instance. :)
I just typed up a rough example on my iPad to make my problem clear. 
Appreciate the tip though.

Comment: Joris, your understanding of actors is correct, that they help achieve thread-safety by preventing concurrent access. It is best to not think of them as being equivalent to serial queues, as they differ in many significant ways.

Comment: @JorisT Actors serialise *concurrent* access to their data. That's not exactly the same as thread safety. Swift can achieve concurrency with only one machine thread.

Comment: @JeremyP – I’m not sure I’m following your point. As discussed in [Eliminate data races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110351/) and [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133) we use actor isolation to avoid data races. But this (just like GCD) is not a single, dedicated thread. It avails itself of random threads from a pool. We simply use actors (and GCD serial queues) to ensure that two different threads won’t access the shared mutable state at the same time.

Comment: @Rob Threads are not part of the abstract model of Swift concurrency but part of the underlying implementation. You can achieve it with only one thread because, when something blocks, the runtime can switch to another task that is waiting for execution. Even in this scenario, you need a means to synchronise access to data and actors can provide that.

Comment: Ah, your point is that it can achieve it on a single thread. Yes, absolutely, it can. It’s quite clever in avoiding unnecessary switches to different threads as it jumps from actor to actor. I thought you were making a stronger assertion, that a given actor can *only* use a single thread, which is not the case. But in retrospect, I think I read too much into your comment. My bad. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a reference to the `Task` for the bearer token request, and `await` it:

```swift
actor APIManager {
    private var bearerTask: Task<Void, Error>?
    
    func execute<R: ResponseProtocol>(request: RequestProtocol, response: R) async throws -> R.Value {
        _ = try await bearerTask?.value
        
        let session = getURLSession()
        let urlRequest: URLRequest = request.buildURLRequest()
        
        let (data, urlResponse) = try await session.data(for: urlRequest)
        
        if let httpURLResponse = urlResponse as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 401 {
            // if 401, only create new bearer task if one hasn’t already been created yet

            if bearerTask == nil {
                bearerTask = Task {
                    defer { bearerTask = nil }
                    try await renewBearerToken()
                }
            }

            // now try request again (which will wait for the bearer task created above

            return try await execute(request: request, response: response)
        }
        
        return decode(data: data)
    }
}
```

I would make the API manager an `actor` (or isolate it to a global actor) to avoid races on `bearerTask`. And I check whether the bearer task is  `nil` to avoid multiple, redundant bearer token requests if you just happened to quickly fire off many requests with the invalid token before the first of them gets around to returning the 401.

But the key observation is that multiple API calls can `await` the same `bearerTask`.